# How can I get the Date modified from a file or stream using DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors

I have been searching through basically all of google and the DXL reference documentation to find a function where I can get a `Date` object from a *filename* or `stream` object but I was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a `Stat`

```
Declaration
    Stat create(Stream s)
    Stat create(string filename)

Operation
Returns a status handle for the stream or file name, which is used in the other Stat functions


bool regular (Stat)
Date modified (Stat)
bool symbolic (Stat)
void delete (Stat)
Date changed (Stat)
string user (Stat)
int mode (Stat)
bool directory (Stat)
int size (Stat)
Date accessed (Stat)
```

Comment: Thanks again Mike, so it was in the documentation! I guess I must have glanced over it in my hurry to get things done.

Comment: Nobody said that it's easy to retrieve information from the dxl reference manual 